# Problems using BULK INSERTwith format file and double quotes in CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and the `BULK INSERT` command referencing a `.csv` file and format file. I have done this successfuly before when all fields (including column headers) but now the data format has changed slightly and the first column heade rand data is NOT wrapped in double quoutes and an having problems in creating the format file.

Example data...

```
Number of Employees;"Employee - First Name (Key)";"Employee - Last Name   (Key)";"Employee - E-Mail Address (Key)"
1;"Joe";"Bloggs";"joebloggs@msn.com"
```

Note, semi-colon is the field separator and first column header and data have no quotes, all following headers and  data do and is consistent

Example fmt format file...

```
12.0
5
1       SQLCHAR             0       0      "\""    0     ""                                                          ""
2       SQLCHAR             2       50      ";"   1  "Number of   Employees"                                        Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLNCHAR            2       510     "\";\""   2    "Employee First Name"                                        Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLNCHAR            2       510     "\";\""   3     "Employee Last Name"                                        Latin1_General_CI_AS
5       SQLNCHAR            2       510     "\"\r\n"  4     "E-Mail Address"                                             Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

I have tried all sorts of delimiter permutations for the first column with the dummy column removed, before and after first column (the above is the the latest) and I still get the same error message...

> Cannot bulk load because the file "\Mypath\import_staff_dq.fmt" is incomplete or could not be read. Operating system error code (null).

The file is always closed.

I have set all fields in the dest table to `VARCHAR` for simplicity

Comment: BULK INSERT doesn't support complex CSV files, ie files with newlines or quoted strings. That's coming in SQL Server 2017. Use SSIS for this. You can use the `Import Data` wizard in SSMS to import CSV data *and* save an SSIS package for reuse. The most common scenario is to use SSIS for import and transformations, not direct bcp or BULK INSERT

Comment: It shuould work with an accomapanying format file ('fmt') which I have used successfully when ALL the fields are wrapped in double quotes but it's not working as described above where the first column is not wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I find xml format files to be easier to understand and create.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
 <RECORD>  
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=';"' MAX_LENGTH="10"/>  
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='";"' MAX_LENGTH="4000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>  
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='";"' MAX_LENGTH="4000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>  
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"\r\n' MAX_LENGTH="4000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>  
 </RECORD>  
 <ROW>  
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="NumberOfEmployees" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>  
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="EmployeeFirstName" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>  
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="EmployeeLastName" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>  
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="EmailAddress" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>  
 </ROW>  
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Using `openrowset(bulk ...)`

```
select *
from openrowset (
    bulk 'c:\tmp.csv'
  , formatfile='c:\tmp.xml'
  , firstrow=2
  ) as t
```

returns:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
| NumberOfEmployees | EmployeeFirstName | EmployeeLastName |   EmailAddress    |
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|                 1 | Joe               | Bloggs           | joebloggs@msn.com |
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Reference:

- [XML Format Files (SQL Server) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187833.aspx)

---

I am also able to get the same results using a non-xml format file like so:

```
12.0
4
1    SQLCHAR    0    0    ";\""       1    NumberOfEmployees   Latin1_General_CI_AS
2    SQLCHAR    0    0     "\";\""    2    EmployeeFirstName   Latin1_General_CI_AS
3    SQLCHAR    0    0     "\";\""    3    EmployeeLastName    Latin1_General_CI_AS
4    SQLCHAR    0    0     "\"\r\n"   4    EmailAddress        Latin1_General_CI_AS
```